# How do I make a mjpg image stream dynamically resize with onclick=newwindow?

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage streaming multiple IP cameras, each camera image is clickable to bring up a new, resizable window. However the image of the mjpg stream in the new window is static in size. I would like the image to resize with the browser window.  If this isn't possible then I can just create a web page for each camera and make it resize the image dynamically, but i'd rather not have to create a page for each camera I have.

I've tried looking up ways to accomplish this but just can't find what I need. I have very limited code knowledge so I just don't know what to search for.

```
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="zm_html_styles.css" type="text/css">
    <script language="javascript">
        var win = null;
        function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll)
        {
        LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
        TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
        settings = 'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
        win = window.open(mypage,myname,settings)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">

<div id'"row1" style="overflow: no; max-height: 256px;">
    <table align="center" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://10.0.0.87/mjpg/video.mjpg" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'name','1920','1440','yes');return false">
            <img src="http://10.0.0.87/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&fps=5" width="365" height="274"></a>

        <td><a href="http://10.0.0.141/mjpg/video.mjpg" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'name','1920','1440','yes');return false">
            <img src="http://10.0.0.141/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&fps=5" width="365" height="274"></a>

        <td><a href="http://10.0.0.78/mjpg/video.mjpg" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'name','1920','1440','yes');return false">
            <img src="http://10.0.0.78/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&fps=5" width="365" height="274"></a>

        <td><a href="http://10.0.0.139/mjpg/video.mjpg" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'name','1920','1440','yes');return false">
            <img src="http://10.0.0.139/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&fps=5" width="365" height="274"></a>

        <td><a href="http://10.0.0.64/mjpg/video.mjpg" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'name','1920','1440','yes');return false">
            <img src="http://10.0.0.64/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&fps=5" width="365" height="274"></a>

        <td><a href="http://10.0.0.83/mjpg/video.mjpg" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'name','1920','1440','yes');return false">
            <img src="http://10.0.0.83/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&fps=5" width="365" height="274"></a>

        <td><a href="http://10.0.0.107/mjpg/video.mjpg" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'name','1920','1440','yes');return false">
            <img src="http://10.0.0.107/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&fps=5" width="365" height="274"></a>

        <td><a href="http://10.0.0.111/mjpg/video.mjpg" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'name','1920','1440','yes');return false">
            <img src="http://10.0.0.111/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&fps=5" width="365" height="274"></a>
    <tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I can't find code to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The best approach would be to post code you've already tried, that isn't working, and then people can offer suggestions of how to improve.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you'll have send a new request when the window resizes. The code would look something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
     let height = window.innerHeight;
     let width = window.innerWidth;
     document.location = `http://myserver/axis-cgi/operator/param.cgi? action=update&Image.I0.Resolution=${width}x${height}`
});
```

But since you have not provided any insight into your code, this is just a guess and my not work. If you want a more precise answer you'll need to provide some code you've attempted and HTML to go along with it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've edited and added some of the web page code I have to my original post. With my very limited understanding I'm thinking I need to add the code or something similar to it into the script section at the top. I'm not sure how to integrate this resize functionality though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MichaelGregory - In that case, a bit has to change to accomplish your goal. Each link in the anchor tag will need to point to an HTML file that independently loads the video and contains the JavaScript required to deal with the window resize. This is necessary because the window you open with `window.open()` runs in its own context and is completely independent from the opener window.

Comment: Ok I was thinking that might be needed. Thanks for the help.